# system.web.compilation.debug vs. system.codedom.compilers.compiler.compilerOptions /define:Debug=True

Tags: asp.net, debugging, configuration, web-config

When I deploy my ASP.NET web app to production, I use a config transform to remove `debug="true"` from `<compilation>`.  However, just today I noticed another section in the web.config that looks like this:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler compilerOptions="/define:Debug=True" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

What is this?  Is the fact that that's there defeating the purpose of removing it from `<compilation>`?  What happens if I remove that attribute as shown above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the fact that that's there defeating the purpose 
>   of removing it from `<compilation>`

From [MSDN C# Compiler Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx)
To open the **debug** the flag on the compiler is the `/debug` not the `/define:Debug=True`

> /debug : **Instruct the compiler to emit debugging information.**
>   /define : **Defines preprocessor symbols.**

So when you define the `Debug=True` you only make true this case of code:

```
#if DEBUG == true
// Compile what is inside here !
#endif
```

the `/define:Debug=True` is not add any additional debug informations, unless you have include them manual with the above code.

### Test page

I use the following code to make tests and see whats happens.

```
    txtDebug.Text = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled.ToString();

    #if DEBUG
    txtDebug.Text +=  "<br>defined Debug is on";
    #endif
    #if DEBUG == true
    txtDebug.Text +=  "<br>defined Debug = true is on";
    #endif
```

### Result 1

Now if the `debug="false"` and with `compilerOptions="/define:Debug=True"` the results are

> false
>   defined Debug = true is on

### Result 2

if the `debug="true"` and `compilerOptions="/define:Debug=True"` the resuls are

> true
>   defined Debug is on
>   defined Debug = true is on

### Result 3

Now I make one more test, I add this line on web.config

```
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" 
    compilerOptions="/define:Debug=True /D:DEBUG,TESTFLAG" 
   type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, 
     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
       warningLevel="4" />
```

And the results are with `debug=false`

> False   (debug is false)
>   defined Debug is on  (but the defined DEBUG now is runs)
>   defined Debug = true is on (This is also runs)
>   test flag  (but the defined extra flag is also runs)

### MSDN

Looking at the [MSDN for the /define (Preprocessor Definition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z(v=vs.71).aspx) I look that the declaration

```
/define:Debug=True
```

is work only for this case of code

```
#if DEBUG == true
txtDebug.Text +=  "<br>defined Debug = true is on";
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry I've put this off.  I am not sure I am understanding the use of `#if DEBUG`.  I cannot get this to return false unless I change the configuration dropdown at the toolbar (where you see Debug, Release, etc) and then rebuild.  Also, what is the difference between `#if DEBUG` and `#if DEBUG == true`?  Lastly, what is your final, objecting answer?  David Ebbo's answer states that having `/define:Debug=True` is the same thing as `debug="true"`.  Does your answer agree with or contradict his answer?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin having `debug="true"` is not the same as  `/define:debug=true` because have higher priority and the define is not working here for that, and I have made a test page and show the results here that proves it. Now I have also in the answer what is the difference between `#if DEBUG` and `#if DEBUG == true`, if you see the test you understand them. I can not write them here again.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Is not the same, and here from msdn is the proof http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx and I will update the answer again

Comment: Having looked at that and an MSDN doc on Debug=true, I believe you are correct.  Awarding you bounty and answer to close this out.

Comment: Which is the full code of Test page ? reommended **codedom configuration** for production environment ?

Answer (score 1):

The string you set in `compilerOptions` is basically a piece of command line that gets added to all compilations.

If you use aspx pages, you can also set it in there so it only applies to one page. e.g.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CompilerOptions="etc..." %>
```

How did you end up with it set to "/define:Debug=True" in your config? It is not typical to have that. But to answer your question, yes, this will effectively turn on Debug regardless of the value of the `debug` attribute.

Unless you have a good reason to have it, I would yank it altogether.